# "Object" does not contain a definition for "name"

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm having an error message that tells me this:

'BankAccount.account' does not contain a definition for 'withdraw'.

Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace BankAccounts
{
class account
{
    protected string name;
    protected float balance;
    public account(string n, float b)
    {
        name = n;
        balance = b;
    }

    public void deposit(float amt)
    {
        balance -= amt;
    }

    public void display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}. Balance: {1}.", name, balance);
    }
}

class savingaccount : account
{
    static int accno = 1000;
    int trans;
    public savingaccount(string s, float b) : base(s, b)
    {
        trans = 0;
        accno++;
    }
    public void withdraw (float amt)
    {
        if (trans >= 10)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Number of transactions exceed 10.");
            return;
        }
        if (balance - amt < 500)
            Console.WriteLine("Below minimum balance.");
        else
        {
            base.withdraw(amt);
            trans++;
        }
    }
    public void deposit(float amt)
    {
        if (trans >= 10)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Number of transactions exceed 10.");
            return;
        }
        base.deposit(amt);
        trans++;
    }
    public void display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}. Account no.: {1}. Balance: {2}", name, accno,        balance);
    }
}

class currentaccount : account
{
    static int accno = 1000;
    public currentaccount(string s, float b) : base(s, b)
    {
        accno++;
    }
    public void withdraw(float amt)
    {
        if (balance - amt < 0)
            Console.WriteLine("No balance in account.");
        else
            balance -= amt;
    }
    public void display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}. Account no.: {1}. Balance: {2}.", name, accno, balance);
    }
}
```

}

I don't understand why it doesn't recognize it. It is a method in the class savingaccount.

Comment: There is no `.withdraw` method in the `account` (it's best to capitalize your class names by the way), yet your derived classes have them - why not include a signature for `.withdraw` in the base class? Can you post how you are using this code? The error message is correct as far as I can see.

Comment: it looks like a lot of these methods should actually be `virtual`/`override`, btw - and doesn't "deposit" usually *increase* the balance?

Answer (score 6):

You're calling

```
base.withdraw(amt);
```

from your class `savingsaccount`. But the base class (`account`) has no such method. So the compiler is absolutely correct.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you simply missed the method from the base type:

```
public virtual void Deposit(float amt)
{
    balance += amt;
}
public virtual void Withdraw(float amt)
{
    balance -= amt;
}
```

Note I changed "deposit" to `+=`, and made the method `virtual` so that subclasses can `override` the method, which is (I strongly suspect) what the intent is here. Additionally, `float` is a really bad choice for storing money. `decimal` might be a better choice. As a stylistic change, I also capitalized the names.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your intention was to define the basic `withdraw` method in the base `account` class, so that it would be inherited by both `savingaccount` and `currentaccount`. You should declare it as `virtual` in order to allow it to be overridden by the derived classes, if required.

```
class account
{
    public virtual void withdraw(float amt)
    {
        if (balance - amt < 0)
            Console.WriteLine("No balance in account.");
        else
            balance -= amt;
    }
}
```

The `currentaccount` class presumably does not need to modify the logic of this inherited method, so you can omit it altogether. On the other hand, in your `savingaccount` class, you can override the method to implement your custom behaviour:

```
class savingaccount : account
{
    public override void withdraw(float amt)
    {
        if (trans >= 10)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Number of transactions exceed 10.");
            return;
        }
        if (balance - amt < 500)
            Console.WriteLine("Below minimum balance.");
        else
        {
            base.withdraw(amt);
            trans++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You call `base.withdraw(amt)` in your `savingaccount` class, but the base class `account` does not define this method.

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely, you'll see that your `account` class in fact doesn't have a `withdraw` method.

I'd guess you meant to have your `account` class contain a virtual method `withdraw`, defined like this:
`public virtual void withdraw(float amt) { ... }`

Then, in your inherited classes you'd want to override this method, like so:

```
class currentaccount : account
{
    public override void withdraw(float amt)
    {
        ...
        base.withdraw(amt)
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

There's also a naming style issue with your code, but this is probably not in the scope of this question :)

Comment: If `account.withdraw` were `abstract` then `base.withdraw()` wouldn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

As everybody pointed out allready, you should declare the withdraw() method on your base class acocunt, so all the derived classes can inherit the method.