# CS0117 error in Visual Studio. Having a class with 2 methods WriteText and WriteNumber

Tags: c#, string, class, methods, instance-variables

I need helping in C# using Visual Studio coding naming a class called Calculator that has these 2 methods WriteText and WriteNumber that satisfy the conditions in the code in the main method.

I tried to write it down but I get these error in Visual studio - Calculator does not contain a definition for "WriteText" and "WriteNumber".

The code below is the one that does not work:

```
namespace CalculatorTest
{
    class Calculator
    {

    }
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s = Calculator.WriteText("Hello world!");
            Console.WriteLine(s);

            string n = Calculator.WriteNumber(53 + 28);
            Console.WriteLine(n);

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message tells you what the problem is - your class Calculator has no methods `WriteText` or `WriteNumber`.

Comment: See e.g. [“Object” does not contain a definition for “name”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13138406/3744182).  You need to add the appropriate methods `public string WriteText(string text)` and `public string WriteNumber(int n)`.  They will need to be static unless you plan to instantiate an instance of `Calculator`, which you are not doing in your code.

Comment: Add the method to the Calculator class like this: `public static void WriteText(string text) { Console.WriteLine(text); }` and remove `Console.WriteLine(s)` or you will repeat the output. Do the same for the other method.